# Add localised items to Excel validation list

Tags: vba, excel, localization, excel-2007

I have 2 validation in-cell drop-down lists:

```
With Cells(1, 3).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="Aktiv;Inaktiv"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

and

```
With Cells(1, 5).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=str
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

First one is filled as above ("Aktiv;Inaktiv"), second one is filled with dates "Jan 17;Feb 17;.."). As you can see, the delimiter used is a semicolon because that's what German Excel syntax dictates.

However, when I want to insert the values via VBA I have to use a comma. This results in the file breaking after saving, closing and reopening every single time without fail. The errors are (roughly) "unreadable content found in file " and "Feature removed: Data validation in /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-Part".

I have recreated this: it breaks when I use the wrong localised delimiter and when I accept the feature removal it deletes my validation lists. How do I do this in VBA, successfully?

---

EDIT: My bad, I didn't mention what using the wrong delimiter does:

Wrong delimiter: inserts items as 1 line: [image: wrong_delim]

Right delimiter: inserts items in 1 line each: [image: right_delim]

Comment: Have you tried putting your entries in a range and then referring to that instead in the DV code?

Comment: No I haven't, but it's a large excel file shared across multiple departments. I would very much like to do everything in the background and not have any information written down on a sheet for someone to mess around with.

Comment: I don't understand: what happens if you use commas in your VBA code? How is `str` "filled"?

Comment: `str` is filled by string-concatenating the items, nothing exciting. I added screencaps of what using the wrong delimiter looks like, above.

Comment: Are your DV strings all under 255 characters? If not, that would cause an error when you reopen the file.

Comment: @Rory Good thinking! The 2nd DV is about 500 characters long. However, when the file breaks, both lists are removed from the sheet. Is that just a precaution or a sign that there is something wrong with both of them?

Comment: Try with just the first and see?

Comment: Was going to say that you could use a hidden sheet, but looks like Rory has solved it anyway.

Comment: @Rory You were right! I tried every combination manually without VBA, the problem is the length of the list in the second DV